# CSS Floats and Nested Lists

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In CSS, I am floating sets of nested lists in order to create dropdown menus.  However, the headers are not nearly as wide as many of the items in their dropdown menus, so the headers end up getting spaced disproportionately (because each of their dropdown components have different widths---apparently a list is as wide as its widest component).  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<body>

    <ul id="navigation">

     <li><a href="#">Header A</a></li>
     <li class="sub">

      <a href="#">Header B</a>

      <ul>

       <li><a href="#">Item AAAAAAAAAAAA</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item BBBBBBBBBBBB</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item CCCCCCCCCCCC</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item DDDDDDDDDDDD</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item EEEEEEEEEEEE</a></li>
      </ul>

     </li>

     <li>
      <a href="#">Header C</a>
     </li>

    </ul>

</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    body {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    }


 #navigation {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 1em;
 background: #000;
 height: 3em;
 list-style: none;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    } 

#navigation > li {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 padding: 0 1em;
}

#navigation > li > a {
 color: #7A7A7A;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 3;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#navigation > li > a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 list-style: none;
 background: rgba(12,13,69,1);
 position: relative;
 top: 10000px;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a {
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 padding: 0.4em;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a:hover {
 background: #00F2FF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation > li.sub:hover ul {
 display: block;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It will be far more helpful to the community of you can post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say what's happening in your specific case.

But here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Menu One
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu One Item One</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu One Item One Submenu Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu One Item Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu Two
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Two Item Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em; }
a:hover { color: #cc0000; }

/* Hide submenu */
nav ul > li > ul,
nav ul > li > ul > li > ul { display:none; }

/* Layout menubar and menus */
nav { background:#ddd; padding:0.25em 0.5em; }
nav > ul > li { cursor: pointer; display:inline-block; padding:0 1em; }
nav > ul > li > ul { background: #ddd; padding:0.5em; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; }
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul { background: #ccc; padding:0.5em; position: absolute; left: 90%; top: 0; z-index: 1001; }

/* show submenu on hover */
nav ul > li:hover > ul,
nav ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul { display:block; width:10em; }
```